# Ten thousand unit circle or more, how to draw it high performance?

Tags: c++, windows, opengl

**Problem**:
In 3D space, there are many points. I need draw a unit circle at the position of each point.
And all circles' normal should always perpendicular to the device's screen and the size is not
changed, even though I rotate or zoom in/out the view.
[image]

**My method**:

At first I have a large array to store the xyz coordinate of each point.

```
for each point in the array:
    apply a model view matrix  // to keep the normal perpendicular and the same size
    draw a unit circle with gl* functions
```

By this method, I get a very bad FPS when the amount of the points is up to 10000.
This's very inefficient. Is there any better method to solve this problem? or some OpenGL
technique can be used?

Comment: I solved this problem by OpenGL **instance rendering**. Check this [link](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/opengl/opengl-instancing-demystified-r3226)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can draw them [instanced](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Rendering#Instancing) (available since 3.3 or extension `ARB_instanced_arrays`)

you prepare a single unit circle for drawing (using a separate attribute for the location which you add to the points in the vertex shader)

the position of each point is put in a separate VBO and you specify the divisor with

```
void glVertexAttribDivisor​(GLuint index​, GLuint divisor​);
```

and then you use

```
void glDrawArraysInstanced​( GLenum mode​, GLint first​, GLsizei count​, GLsizei instancecount​);
```

with count the number of vertexes in your `circle` and `instancecount` the number of points

Comment: You say "each point is put in a separate VBO". That sounds extremely inefficient, and I don't see how it could even work. All the points need to be in the same VBO.

Comment: no I meant the array with point locations is put in a single VBO separate from the vertexes for the circle

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your approach are the many many OpenGL calls you require.

First you should model your circles as "particles". Each particle has a position and perhaps a color. You can even add a size.

You can render particles in two ways: either a line loop (i.e. a circle), or an alpha blended particle texture with a circle. The first uses more vertices and is somehow limited to how it looks. The latter uses only two triangles and is much more flexible, but perhaps a bit heavy on the fill rate.

For both cases, you should first create all the primitives required for rendering (either lines or quads). Store the vertices and indices in a [vertex buffer object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_Buffer_Object). Then you can draw  with exactly one draw call.

With modern OpenGL (3.2+) you can use [geometry shaders](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Geometry_Shader) to create the particle mesh on the fly on the GPU. This is probably faster.

The detailed process is not very complicated, but out of scope for an answer here. Search on the internet for resources on the steps indicated above and feel free to ask more specific questions here.

Comment: Thanks. the particles can be draw with vbo, but we must draw the particles so many times. Because a matrix must be applied before each draw to make the particle the right position and scale size. I have try the vbo and it's still ineffiecient.

Comment: All the points' coordinates can store by a vbo. but glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS..) only draw many points, not the circle. Any idea??

Answer (score 0):

You have an array with the XYZ positions of each point. Copy all that data into a VBO which you will use as the vertex data.

The draw code will just be glVertexAttribPointer (or glBindArray with a VAO) and then glDrawArrays with n == number of points in the array.

Normally this would just give you lots of individual dots.

OpenGL has point sprites, where each point is drawn as a quad, screen aligned, with size in pixels specified by the vertex shader. (There's an implementation limit which IIRC is guaranteed to be at least 63 pixels, but that's probably big enough for your case.) So you need to enable GL_PROGRAM_POINT_SIZE and have your vertex shader assign something to gl_PointSize. (You could make the size depend on the perspective distance if you liked.)

The last step is that these point sprites can be textured. The fragment shader gets the texture coordinates from 0.0 to 1.0 for each pixel within the quad as builtin gl_PointCoord. Create a small texture map with the image of your circle, setting the pixels you don't want to be transparent, and use it to set the color in your fragment shader.

See Chapter 9 of the 6th edition OpenGL SuperBible for the code. Hope this helps.